# Mysqli COUNT with variable that contains apostrophe

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to run a count on my DB and this works correctly except when one of the usernames contains an apostrophe.

I am using prepared statements, so I assume its being escaped correctly?

Can someone tell me what is wrong?

```
$var1 = $_SESSION['SESS_STAFF_NAME'];
$qry = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE staff = ?" ;
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($qry);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $var1);                          
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$total_items = $result->fetch_row();
$rows = $total_items[0];
echo $rows;
```

I only get the error issue when the staff variable contains a `'`, e.g. “O'Connor”; it seems to be returning a total count of all records.

Comment: Total count of records? So, "it seems" or you are positively sure?

Comment: It was actually correct, I needed to add another variable to only show active fields (one of my table rows) Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Normally, this is the same thing as the PDO prepared statement: queries are pre-compiled, that guaranteed protection against SQL injection. No need to escape bind params.

Test :

```
ThinkPad-T420 ~ $ cat test.php
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
    $var = "String' thing"; // It's working too with $var = 'String\' thing'
    $dbh = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "sitri", "test");
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS nb FROM t WHERE field = ?";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $var);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $total_items = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo "total=" . $total_items['nb'] . "\n";
?>
ThinkPad-T420 ~ $ echo "DESC t"|mysql -uroot -p"${passwd}" test
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
field   varchar(254)    YES     NULL    
ThinkPad-T420 ~ $ echo "SELECT * FROM t;"|mysql -uroot -p"${passwd}" test
field
String' thing
ThinkPad-T420 ~ $ ./test.php 
total=1
```

Comment: `mysql` does also have a `-e` parameter for direct statement execution.

Comment: Yes thank you. I suspected the existence of such an option but it was just for give an example. This topic is far from being focused on how to run a query from the command line. Also I don't understand this downvote but, anyway it doesn't matter ...